# Is inducing a retrograde ejaculation harmful?

Tags: ejaculation, prostate, orgasm-climax, urethra, semen

By applying pressure on the perineum just before ejaculation, a man can induce retrograde ejaculation in which the semen is redirected to the bladder. This is obviously different from unintentional retrograde ejaculation, which is caused by some pathology.

I have read confusing things about whether inducing retrograde ejaculation is safe. Wikipedia for example says,

> Many doctors also do not recommend [retrograde ejaculation] due to the risk of putting pressure on the pudendal nerve, which can cause numbness in the penis. [citation needed]

Other sources I have found said an induced retrograde ejaculation could damage the sphincter or the prostate, or that doing it frequently over a longer period of time could cause a retrograde ejaculation to occur even when not induced, thus causing infertility.

No actual citation was given to any of this.

Is there any medical evidence about the safety of inducing a retrograde ejaculation? Does it cause short-term damage? What about long-term?

Comment: What sources have you consulted in researching this question?

Comment: @Thomas Wikis and personal testimonies in blogs and forums. In other words, sources that aren't reliable without scientific backing.